# how do i handle xml in chunks using python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently loading xml into memory using ElementTree, this is not a problem when the files are of reasonable size however some of the files i am dealing with are over 500MB in size and this means the xml fails to load into memory. My current code is pretty standard as follows:

```
    tree = ET.parse(xmlLoc)
    root= tree.getroot()
            for element in root.iter(elementName):
                # do work here
```

Is there a way of doing the above in chunks?

Comment: What about using SAX parser ? https://wiki.python.org/moin/Tutorials%20on%20XML%20processing%20with%20Python

Comment: Have you already tried this one http://baraujo.net/blog/?p=81

Comment: is there sample code which will do similar to the above?